# Excel sum/max-min multiple rows, insert new row and delete added rows

Tags: excel, summary, sumifs, maxifs

I have the Excel data shown below. Column A has the ID, columns B and C have segments of values associated with the ID, and Columns D and E are general descriptions of the ID (associated with the ID, not individual segments). The data has about 600 IDs and is about 1000 rows long.

| ID | Value 1 | Value 2 | Descr 1 | Descr 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2.5 | 1.8 | a | x1 |
| 11 | 2.3 | 1.1 | a | x1 |
| 11 | 1.9 | 1.6 | a | x1 |
| 12 | 3.7 | 3.5 | b | x2 |
| 12 | 3.9 | 1.5 | b | x2 |
| 13 | 2.5 | 0.2 | c | x3 |
| 13 | 2.6 | 4.1 | c | x3 |
| 13 | 2 | 4.8 | c | x3 |
| 13 | 2.7 | 1.8 | c | x3 |

I am trying to create a single row for each ID. This row will add up values in columns B and C, and delete repeated descriptions, wherever the ID matches in column A.

I have tried using SUMIF, but I can't figure out how to automate that over the entire row of data. I believe there should be a better function/method to do this. Expected is a table with unique ID, values, and description.

| ID | Value 1 | Value 2 | Descr 1 | Descr 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 6.7 | 4.5 | a | x1 |
| 12 | 7.6 | 5.0 | b | x2 |
| 13 | 9.8 | 10.9 | c | x3 |

---

*Edited*

---

@Ike Solution below worked for me. I was trying to get max value 1 and min value 2 for each ID. I edited Ike Solution to below, but it threw up a #Value! error

```
=LET(data,A1:E10,
       uIDs, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(data,1,4,5)),
       aValues, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(uIDs), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, MIN(IF(INDEX(data,,1),INDEX(uIDs,r,1),INDEX(data,,c+1))))
                                                    ),
       bValues, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(uIDs), 1, LAMBDA(j,k, MAX(IF(INDEX(data,,1),INDEX(uIDs,j,1),INDEX(data,,k+1))))
                                                    ),
      CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(uIDs,aValues, bValues),1,4,5,2,3))
```

Comment: what happens if you have more than one descr 1 and descr 2 per ID?

Comment: Nothing happens. The descr are not used in any calculations.

Comment: So there would be another line with that ID and other desc?

Comment: Yes. but from this data, the descr is related to the ID. So the entry with ID 11 will always have descr1 = "a", and descr2 = "X1", no matter how many segments of values there is.

Comment: I see that in this test data, but wanted to make sure any answer will work for your data as a whole.  Because if we answer for your test data and your full data has different descriptions for the same ID then we would be creating something that works for this test and not your real data.  Hense the questions, been burned too many times.

Comment: I understand. In the real data, the IDs are road IDs, which is a concatenation of city_code, the road_code, etc etc. The descriptions are just the codes for the cities and roads. 

The data was entered for segments of roads, from location_x to location_y. I am trying to get the data for each road. So for each road, the city and road codes will not change.

Comment: I have edited the `Title` of the post because as per edit of OP, OP is desiring to achieve the min and max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If applicable one could use `GROUPBY()` works with `MS365` for **Beta** Versions.

[image]

---

```
=CHOOSECOLS(GROUPBY(HSTACK(A1:A10,D1:E10),B1:C10,SUM,3,0),1,4,5,2,3)
```

---

**MSFT Documentations:** **[GROUPBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/groupby-function-5e08ae8c-6800-4b72-b623-c41773611505)** or **[PIVOTBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pivotby-function-de86516a-90ad-4ced-8522-3a25fac389cf)**

---

**Edit:** As per the new update by OP

[image]

---

```
=CHOOSECOLS(DROP(GROUPBY(HSTACK(A1:A10,D1:E10),B1:C10,HSTACK(MAX,MIN),3,0),1),1,4,5,2,3)
```

---

### Using One `LAMBDA()` Helper Function `MAKEARRAY()` with `AGGREGATE()` function to get the desired output of `MIN` & `MAX` values:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data,A2:E10,
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(_Data,1,4,5)),
     _MinMax, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
              INDEX(AGGREGATE({15,14},6,
              INDEX(HSTACK(INDEX(_Data,,2),INDEX(_Data,,3)),,c)/
              (INDEX(_Data,,1)=INDEX(_Uniq,r,1)),1),c))),
     _Answer, CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(_Uniq,_MinMax),1,4,5,2,3),
     VSTACK({"ID","Min","Max","Descr 1","Descr 2"},_Answer))
```

---

Also for `MAX` and `MIN` one needs to interchange the **function_num** in the `AGGREGATE()` function:

[image]

---

**Test Case:**

[image]

---

**Edit:** Forgot to use `CHOOSECOLS()` so here is an updated version:

```
=LET(
     _Data,A2:E19,
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(_Data,1,4,5)),
     _MinMax, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
              INDEX(AGGREGATE({15,14},6,
              INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(_Data,2,3),,c)/
              (INDEX(_Data,,1)=INDEX(_Uniq,r,1)),1),c))),
     _Answer, CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(_Uniq,_MinMax),1,4,5,2,3),
     VSTACK({"ID","Min","Max","Descr 1","Descr 2"},_Answer))
```

---

Comment: Thank you, but Groupby did not work for me. It shows a #Name? Error

Comment: @DiplomatX that is why I have written `if applicable` and works with `MS365` Beta Versions. Also added `MSFT Doc`

Comment: @DiplomatX you need to enable the Office Insider feature to have access to `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()` and just changing the `SUM` to `MAX` will give you the new expected output as well

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that. But I just accepted one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```vb
=LET(data,A2:E10,
uIDs, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(data,1,4,5)),
sValues,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(uIDs),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
                     SUMIF(INDEX(data,,1),INDEX(uIDs,r,1),INDEX(data,,c+1)))),
CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(uIDs,sValues),1,4,5,2,3))
```

`sValues` creates the sums per unique ID.

Comment: Thank you, this works! What if i want to choose the max value from Column B and Column C instead of summing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivottable functionality along with formulas like SUMIF to summarize the data

Answer (score 0):

After some reading, figured out how to use the maxifs and minifs function. Solved it with the code below (an edit of Ike's answer):

```
=LET(data,A2:A10,
       uIDs, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(data,1,4,5)),
       startValues, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(uIDs), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, MINIFS(INDEX(data,,c+1),  INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(uIDs,r,1)))
                                                    ),
       endValues, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(uIDs), 1, LAMBDA(j,k, MAXIFS(INDEX(data,,k+2),  INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(uIDs,j,1)))
                                                    ),
      CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(uIDs,startValues, endValues),1,2,3,4,5))
```

Comment: You are presently using two `LAMBDA()` helper function which definitely will slow down the working functionality of `Excel` do check my updated answer using `MAKEARRAY()` with `AGGREGATE()` it uses one `LAMBDA()` helper function and does the same work, but will be faster.